# Share a pdf file to WhatsApp directly, without using a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, whatsapp, url-scheme

I am using below code to send a text to a new WhatsApp number using a WhatsApp Url scheme instead of UIActivityViewController.

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=+9197******2&text=Hi Hello"

if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:
   CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed){
              
  if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
                 
      if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL){
                          
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      } else {
          UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL)
      }

} else {
    print("Install Whatsapp")
}
```

My current requirement is to share a Pdf file to a new WhatsApp number using WhatsApp Url scheme. Can anyone help me with this..

Comment: Hi Scriptable, thanks for the response but I need it using a WhatsApp Url scheme instead of UIActivityViewController.

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the pdf file via url, it's make nonsense.
There are another way you can do is custom the UIActivityViewController.
You can refer this tutorial for UIActivityViewController customization: https://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: HI Minh Van, my requirement is to directly send a file to WhatsApp without displaying UIActivityViewController.

Comment: you can open whatsApp but it's impossible to pass file via url